# Shell script not running in git bash

Tags: windows, bash, git, shell, git-bash

I have created a shell script that automatically downloads local copies of my repositories in github. The script utilizes ssh to clone the repos so it gets both private and public ones. Here is the script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GITHUB_USERNAME="andwati"

DESTINATION_FOLDER=~/GitHub


clone_repositories() {
    local parent_dir=$1
    local url=$2

    # Extract the repository name from the URL
    local repo_name=$(basename "${url%.git}")

    # Clone the repository into the specified folder
    git clone "$url" "$parent_dir/$repo_name"

    # Move into the cloned repository folder
    cd "$parent_dir/$repo_name" || exit

    # If there are submodules, initialize and update them
    if [ -f ".gitmodules" ]; then
        git submodule init
        git submodule update
    fi

    # Recursively clone submodules if any
    if [ -f ".gitmodules" ]; then
        git submodule foreach --recursive "$0" "$parent_dir/$repo_name"
    fi

    # Move back to the parent folder
    cd "$parent_dir" || exit
}

repositories=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$GITHUB_USERNAME/repos?per_page=100" | grep -o 'git@[^"]*')

mkdir -p $DESTINATION_FOLDER


cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER" || exit

for repository in $repositories; do
    clone_repositories "$DESTINATION_FOLDER" "$repository"
done
```

I usually call the script in git bash by running `./repo_sync.sh`. Now the command exits after a few seconds without any feedback . I have also tried using `bash ./repo_sync.sh`

Comment: Git bash is broken. Use wsl, msys2, cygwin, etc. instead

Comment: You're cloning every time? Is this always run on the same system?

Comment: Call it with `bash -x ./repo_sync.sh` to see where it fails. Maybe you can then work around the issue Git bash seems to have.

Comment: Moving back to original directory while in a loop is a bad idea.  Since you're running multiple processes at every iteration and your function does not modify or save data to a variable, run your function or some parts of it in a subshell instead.  Don't make your function exit the script.  Just make it return an error code then in the loop, add an `|| exit` to your command.

Comment: @JimRedmond I created it a while back in my distro hopping days while exploring linux

Comment: @Joe calling it that way works

Comment: @oguzismail "Git bash is broken"? It's clearly not. If *you* expect it to be a full linux bash while it does not present itself as one, the problem is not on the software, if I may.

Comment: @RomainValeri see OP's self-answer, it's evidently broken.

Answer (score 0):

Running the script by calling `bash -x ./repo_sync.sh` makes it to work as intended as suggested by @Joe.